# Exporting an audio recording in MS Word 2008 (Mac)

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, audio-recording, microsoft-word-2008

I have recorded a lecture in Microsoft Word 2008 for Mac. Now I would like to export the recording from the Word file as an `.mp3` or some other audio format. How can I go about doing that?

This is my current screen:

[image: Microsoft Word Audio Recording Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Just in case anyone else finds themselves in this situation, the following steps will export the audio as an `.mp4` audio file:

```
Tools --> Audio Notes --> Export Audio...
```

[image: Exporting Audio]